# html table format

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to type inside the table without having it expanded when the text reaches the edge. Instead, I want the width to be fixed so that the text automatically goes on to the next line every time it reaches the end.

```
<table width='100%' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' border='2' style='table-layout:fixed';>
<tr>
<td align='center'>Part Number</td>
<td align='center'>NSN</td>
<td align='center'>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'>0593500 00000000000000 55050000 22222</td>
<td align='center'>NULL</td>
<td align='center'>STONEGUARD</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: word wrapping is what you want

Comment: Put the code in Fiddle Or something similar , ur problem is not clearly stated

Comment: I don't want exact word wrapping. Once the fixed length is reached for a column it should come next line automatically without expand the column width

Comment: That should happen if you define a set width for the table/column, which you have not in the HTML you provided.

Comment: You’re now setting table layout to fixed but do not set any column or cell widths. This implies that the browser allocates column widths according to the first row, and with short contents like here, this means that the available space is evenly divided between the columns. Please specify what you would want to happen instead.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
<tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word">word word word</td></tr>
</table>
```